# EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode 0x0) with 32-bit simulator

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to figure out how this innocent line could crash the app. The same code works on 64-bit simulators (iPhone 5s or later) but would crash on 32-bit simulators whenever `new_or_used` (an optional String in an NSManagedObject) is accessed. The stack trace does not seem helpful.

Any insights appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened again just recently, and it was due to the variable starting with "new". [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS when deallocating an NSManagedObject after reading a specific NSManagedProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687218/nspersistentstorecoordinator-throws-exc-bad-access-when-deallocating-an-nsmanage)

Answer (score 0):

According to your image seems the compiler try to use an already deallocated String.

To avoid your crash, try to correct your code as :

```
if let newOrUsed = itemPriceGuide.new_or_used as? String {
   // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I can't do that as `new_or_used` is already an optional String. Doing so only gives the "Downcast from String? to String only unwraps optionals" error.

Comment: To make if let working and avoid the crash you must declare that string as non optional, then you can also check is is empty. When you declare it as an optional you accept nil as a possible value