# NSPersistentStoreCoordinator throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS when deallocating an NSManagedObject after reading a specific NSManagedProperty

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nspersistentstore

## Error Description

I have an app with some data stored locally using core data (backed by SQLite) and the following `NSManagedObject` subclass

```
import CoreData

@objc(ScoutingEventData)
class ScoutingEventData: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id: String?
    @NSManaged var type: String?
    @NSManaged var entityId: String?
    @NSManaged var oldStateJson: NSData?
    @NSManaged var newStateJson: NSData?
    @NSManaged var eventDate: NSDate?

    func toInsertEvent() throws -> ScoutingEvent.Insert {
        guard let id = id else { fatalError("events should have an event id") }
        guard let data = newStateJson else { fatalError("insert event should have newStateJson stored") }
    
        // If I uncomment this line, the error goes away. 
        // Somehow by ensuring that data never gets deallocated, the error never occurs.
        // globallllll = data
  
        return ScoutingEvent.Insert(id: id, entity: try ScoutingEntity.from(data))
    }
}

// debugging var to prevent data from being deallocated
var globallllll: NSData?
```

As mentioned in the comment in the snippet above, there is an error occurring if I allow the value I read out of the `newStateJson` property to be deallocated.

The error I receive comes from a background thread:

[image: bad access]

If I enable zombies in the diagnostic tool, I get this instead

[image]

And I also get the following message in the console if zombies are enabled:

> 2016-11-18 16:26:13.773 ScoutingData_Example[51750:4716636] *** -[CFData release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f8c4eb10ae0

And the following stack trace:

[image]

---

## What I've Tried So Far

I have tried storing the `NSManagedObjectContext` which was used to fetch this data in a static variable to ensure that the context never gets deallocated, but that had no effect.

I have tried converting the `NSData?` properties to `String?` properties, and storing the data as a Base64 encoded string instead of binary data (and also updating the backing model), but that had no effect either. The error still persisted.

I have tried commenting out the code that reads the property, and the error dissappeared, but that is obviously not an acceptable solution.

I have tried storing the value in a global variable after reading it, to prevent it from ever being deallocated, and the error dissappeared, but that is also not a valid solution.

I have tried commenting out all the code that *uses* the value, and instead only printing the value to the console, and the error persisted. This leads me to believe that **the act of accessing the property at all, and then deallocating it later, is what creates the conditions for this error.**

---

I am pretty stumped. It seems really odd that it should matter what I do with the data after I read it, and it seems especially odd that anything happens on a background thread when it gets deallocated.

What's even more odd is that it seems specific to this one property. For instance, the id property which I read right above the line that reads the newDataJson property doesn't cause any problems. You might think thats different because the id is a string, not NSData, but I tried converting my NSData property to a string property instead, and it still didn't change the error.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

## Edit

Not sure if this will help, but here's my model schema

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the property a name that doesn't start with `new`. I have had similar problems and had to rename my property to something like `theNewState`. I think the `new` prefix has special meaning and confuses ARC memory management.

Edit: reference [Apple ARC release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), see the section saying "You cannot give an accessor a name that begins with new." So it's actually the accessor/getter name, not the property name itself.

Comment: This is amazing and ridiculous. Thank you so much. I can't imagine how long it would have taken to come across that